# Avatar option on login screen?

Tags: login, mobile-application, signup-signon

Is it ok to give users option to put their photo while login into the app?
Isn't that too much in the start?

Answer (score 4):

Why would someone want to select an avatar during the login process?

I'll assume what you want to say is selecting avatar while onboarding or signup process.

It's almost always advisable to keep the onboarding flow as minimal as possible. If your app can't do without an avatar (can't think of any example) then there is no option for you other than asking for an avatar at the signup time.

The industry standard process for such practices are once the signup process is complete, take the user directly to the page where he/she can complete her profile with providing essential information.

This seems like the best approach, but I'd suggest to use this approach only when a complete profile is VERY important to use the app (ie a dating app would work better with a profile pic). If it can be avoided, it should be avoided, A low information diet is always a good practice for any platform/solution.

Comment: "If your app can't do without an avatar (can't think of any example) then there is no option for you other than asking for an avatar at the signup time."  **Not true.**  Many sites have a minimal sign up process, and don't even collect the minimum information necessary to use the site.  They just get your name and email, then once you are registered ask you to give the necessary information.